# Converting custom integer wrapper to boolean

Tags: c++, boolean, type-conversion, wrapper

Suppose i have a custom wrapper around a primitive C++ type:

```
class myInt
{
    public:
        /*stuff here*/
    private:
        unsigned int data;
}
```

How can i make

```
myInt mi;  
if(mi){...}
```

behave in a way you would expect from a normal integer?
All i can think of is to write an explicit boolean cast, or perhaps override operator==.
Something like:

```
if(bool(mi)){...}
if(mi.toBool()){...}
if(mi==true){..}
```

All these do serve the purpose but look quite ugly and artificial.
Is there another option i am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your following cast operator, something like:

```
class myInt
{
    public:
        operator bool() const { return data != 0; }

    private:
        unsigned int data;
}
```

It is by default implicit (it means that it will be used every time the compiler finds it does need a bool and you provides a myInt). Since c++11 you can mark it as explicit, forcing the usage to be restricted to explicit cast, before that it was always implicit.

But you should note that it is often a bad idea and should be avoided: check [the safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) for more lecture.

Another option close to your desire and a lot safer is the overload of the `!` operator:

```
class myInt
{
    public:
        bool operator!() const { return data == 0; }

    private:
        unsigned int data;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to drop the wrapper altogether.